# Function keys not working in Mac Keyboard on windows

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, boot-camp

I am using a mac keyboard on Windows. The function keys F7 - F12 are not working. In an attempt to fix this problem I installed BootCamp drivers from Apple. Now these keys are working as Media keys (Back, Play.pause, Nest, Mute, Volume Down and Volume  UP). 
Since I work on Visual Studio most of the time, I need the function keys for debugging. Is there some way to get the original Functions for those keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Control Panel -> BootCamp. 
You should find an option called "Use the F1-F12 keys to control software features" under keyboard tab.